# How do I verify a class method is called with the expected parameters using Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, minitest, stub

How do I verify a class method is called with the expected parameters using Minitest?

I want to test this method (highly simplified for the purposes of this question):

```
 def toggle
    EntryAnalyzer.update('val1', 'val2')
  end
```

Specifically, I want to verify that `update` is called with `val1` and `val2` as parameters.

This is what I have currently:

```
 test "#toggle updates the entry" do
    called = false
    mock_update = ->(p1, p2) do
      assert_equal 'val1', p1
      assert_equal 'val2', p2
      called = true
    end

    EntryAnalyzer.stub :update, mock_update do
      testobj.toggle
    end

    assert called    
  end
```

The test above works as expected, but it seems as if I'm "reinventing the wheel".  Is there a way to use a Mock and a stub as I would if I were verifying a call to an instance variable?

(If it matters, I'm trying to test a controller in Rails.)

Comment: The linked article does answer my question (thanks); but, I wasn't able to find it by searching. I'm guessing that is because the title of the question makes no mention of mocking _class_ methods. (So, I don't know if it didn't come up in my search, or if I just didn't read the article because the title didn't look like what I needed.)